# How can I import a sqlite database created in django?

Tags: mysql, database, django, phpmyadmin

Iam a beginner to django. I did run syncdb after mentioning the database file in manage.py. Is it possible to view the contents (tables) of the database in mysql or phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `dbshell`:

```
python manage.py dbshell
```

This will put you in a shell as if running `mysql` with the correct connection params.

If you want to use `phpmyadmin` with it, that's a matter of correct `phpmyadmin` configuration, which depends only on your database, it has nothing to do with Django. So check your `phpmyadmin` settings and configure your database the same way you did in `settings.py` of the Django project.

Answer (score 1):

phpMyAdmin does not support SQLite databases.